# Unix mail -s command hangs without send

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, email

I know the common command to send email from shell is:

```
mail -s 'Some Subject' recipient@domain.com
```

When I do this however, things just hang. No errors returned, no messages sent and seemingly nothing put in the qmail queue. When I try to email my personal email address, the thing just hangs and does not create any entries in the qmail log files.

Are there other things I could be checking to see what the issue might be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's waiting for you to type in the message body.

Once you finish typing the message body, you can terminate the entry by either hitting ctrl-D on a new line, or having a "." (a period) as the first character of a new line.

You will then get a prompt for the "CC" if you want to add any addresses for the CC field.

After you enter that, or hit ENTER, it will send.

Example:

```
$ mail -s "Test message" recipient@example.com
This is a test message
.
Cc: 
$
```

You can also pass in a message body via stdin, e.g., `cat /path/to/file.txt > mail -s "Test Message" recipient@domain.com`, and the message body will be the contents of file.txt.  This works better if file.txt is plaintext.